# SQLAlchemy dynamic column_property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
        Customer,
        customer,
        properties={
            "full_name": column_property(full_name()),
        },
    )
```

if full_name is:

```
def full_name():
    return customer.c.first_name + " " + customer.c.last_name
```

it works fine.

But if full_name is:

```
def full_name():
    result = customer.c.first_name
    if customer.c.last_name:
        result = result + " " + customer.c.last_name
    return result
```

It doesn't work at all.

How to define dynamic column property in classical mapping/Core?
So I could filter by this full_name

Comment: I curious ablot this before. Is there any api in sqlachemy can do this? 
but i can sugget that if you write exucute('<some sql>') will not take you so much time.